# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on Document.adoptNode()

Tags: java, xml, document

I'm getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when I call `adoptNode()` from the Document.
The problem occurs on the 10th call to the method.

The error occurs on line

```
nodeToPutSignature.getOwnerDocument().adoptNode(signature);
```

All the method code:

```
Document tempDocument = new XmlParser().getDocument();
// Sign the temporary Document using xmldsig
sign(tempDocument, getAddress());
tempDocument = XmlTools.newDocument(XmlTools.nodeToString(tempDocument));
// Signature tag from temporary document
final Node signature = XmlTools.getNode(tempDocument, getAddress() + "//Signature");
final Node nodeToPutSignature = XmlTools.getNode(node, 
                                            XPathTools.getXPath(signature.getParentNode()));
// Put the signature tag on the document
nodeToPutSignature.getOwnerDocument().adoptNode(signature);
nodeToPutSignature.appendChild(signature);
```

All the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 35
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.clearChunkIndex(DeferredDocumentImpl.java:2023)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getLastChild(DeferredDocumentImpl.java:826)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getLastChild(DeferredDocumentImpl.java:811)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.synchronizeChildren(DeferredDocumentImpl.java:1693)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredAttrImpl.synchronizeChildren(DeferredAttrImpl.java:142)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.AttrImpl.setOwnerDocument(AttrImpl.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NamedNodeMapImpl.setOwnerDocument(NamedNodeMapImpl.java:405)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementImpl.setOwnerDocument(ElementImpl.java:235)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.setOwnerDocument(ParentNode.java:184)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementImpl.setOwnerDocument(ElementImpl.java:233)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.setOwnerDocument(ParentNode.java:184)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementImpl.setOwnerDocument(ElementImpl.java:233)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.adoptNode(CoreDocumentImpl.java:1874)
    at br.gov.serpro.testtool.xml.testtool.tag.Sign.visit(Sign.java:67)
```

Comment: Given that the error occurs in the library's code DeferredDocumentImpl.java:2023 it looks like a bug. Can you try to use the latest Xerces from apache.org instead of the one provided in the Java JRE?

Comment: @martin-honnen
Is it http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl/2.11.0 that you're talking about?

Comment: @martin-honnen thank you so much, it solved the problem.

signature = XmlTools.newNode(XmlTools.nodeToString(signature));
It solves it too but I prefer the Martin's solution

Comment: I was thinking about http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/ but it seems you have got it from a Maven repository which is obviously fine too.